# Apply new levels across columns via loop

Tags: r, for-loop

Apologize for this question I suspect the answer is easy, but I can't find a solution.

I have a data frame with a set of columns that I'd like to clean up.

the column names in the data frame are:
   worksheet$abx.1  all the way to worksheet$abx.9  (these columns are not successive)

```
  abx.1 <-  c('tazocin', 'pip-tazo', 'piperacillin')
 start.1 <- as.Date(c ('2010-01-01', '2010-01-07', '2010-01-22'))
 abx.2 <-  c('vancomcyin', 'ciprofloxacin', 'piperacillin')
 start.2 <- as.Date(c ('2010-01-01', '2010-01-07', '2010-01-22'))
 worksheet <- data.frame(abx.1, start.1, abx.2, start.2)
```

I would like to apply the following code across all the "abx" columns.

```
    levels(worksheet$abx.1)[levels(worksheet$abx.1) %in% c("Cefazolin", 'IV Cefazolin', 'cefazolin')] <- "cefazolin"
    levels(worksheet$abx.1)[levels(worksheet$abx.1) %in% c("Ceftriaxone", 'ceftriaxone', 'IV Ceftriaxone')] <- "ceftriaxone"
    levels(worksheet$abx.1)[levels(worksheet$abx.1) %in% c("Cefuroxime Axetil", 'Cefuroxime')] <- "cefuroxime"
    levels(worksheet$abx.1)[levels(worksheet$abx.1) %in% c("Piperacillin/Taz", "pip-tazo", 'Pip-tazo', 'Pip-Tazo' )] <- "pip-tazo"
    levels(worksheet$abx.1)[levels(worksheet$abx.1) %in% c('moxifloxacin', 'Moxifloxacin')] <- "moxifloxacin"
```

Is there an easy way to do this?  I'm assuming a for loop is the approach to take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might first simplify the re-coding a bit. If you define the substitutions in a list

```
newlevels <- list(
    "cefazolin" =  c("Cefazolin", 'IV Cefazolin', 'cefazolin'),
    "ceftriaxone" = c("Ceftriaxone", 'ceftriaxone', 'IV Ceftriaxone'),
    "cefuroxime" = c("Cefuroxime Axetil", 'Cefuroxime'),
    "pip-tazo" = c("Piperacillin/Taz", "pip-tazo", 'Pip-tazo', 'Pip-Tazo' ),
    "moxifloxacin" = c('moxifloxacin', 'Moxifloxacin')
)
```

We can also define a helper function for replacing the levels

```
swaplevels <- function(x, value) {
    untouched<-setdiff(levels(x), unlist(value))
    newcodes<-c(setNames(as.list(untouched), untouched), value)
    levels(x)<-newcodes
    x
}
```

Note this is similar to the built in function of `levels<-` but we've added a case where we preserve levels not in the re-assignment list. If you didn't need that feature, you could just use `levels<-` directly. Finally, we can apply this function to all your `abx` columns with

```
abxcols <- grep("^abx",colnames(worksheet))
worksheet[, abxcols] <- lapply(worksheet[,abxcols], swaplevels, newlevels)
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.Flick, I'll take some time and study this. Appreciate the response